# Tell the compiler that a generic return type doesn't borrow any references to arguments?

Tags: rust, callback, reference, borrow-checker

tldr;> Given a trait function that takes a generic callback argument which returns an associated type, the compiler complains that the associated type may borrow arguments from the callback function. Is there any way to tell the compiler that this is not the case?

Details:
I'm planning on implementing a trait function which takes a callback argument and want to force implementations of that trait function to actually call that callback. I do this by having the callback return a type that can only be constructed by calling this callback, and by forcing the trait function to return that type.

```rust
/// If this type is used as a generic argument in a trait function and that trait function
/// returns `CallbackResult`, then that enforces that any implementation of that
/// trait function must call the callback.
pub trait Callback<T> {
    type CallbackResult;

    fn call(self, v: T) -> Self::CallbackResult;
}
```

Example on how this would be used:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
  fn func<C>(&self, callback: C) -> C::CallbackResult
  where
    C: Callback<i32>;
}

struct MyStruct {}
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
  fn func<C>(&self, callback: C) -> C::CallbackResult
  where
    C: Callback<i32>,
  {
    // The compiler forces us to call callback because that's the only way
    // for us to create a value of type C::CallbackResult.
    let v = 42;
    callback.call(v)
  }
}
```

This works: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=440f5d1618c3925118fbe6fac1d06dbe)

The problem comes in when the callback takes a reference:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
  fn func<C>(&self, callback: C) -> <C as Callback<&i32>>::CallbackResult
  where
    C: for <'a> Callback<&'a i32>;
}

struct MyStruct {}
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
  fn func<C>(&self, callback: C) -> <C as Callback<&i32>>::CallbackResult
  where
    C: for<'a> Callback<&'a i32>,
  {
    // The compiler forces us to call callback because that's the only way
    // for us to create a value of type C::CallbackResult.
    let v = 42;
    callback.call(&v)
  }
}
```

This now fails with:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `v`
  --> src/lib.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     callback.call(&v)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--^
   |     |             |
   |     |             `v` is borrowed here
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b969648fd2119804c72aa56194ce6c7)

So it seems that Rust assumes that `CallbackResult` may keep a reference to `v`. Is there a way to tell the compiler that it doesn't? I tried to add a bound `CallbackResult: 'static` to the associated type but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I feel like `'static` should've worked, so not sure there's a way to do this.

Comment: Adding the method generic constraint `for<'a> <C as Callback<&'a i32>>::CallbackResult: 'static` doesn't help either. This seems like it might be a bug.

Comment: Hmm, changing the signature to `fn func<C, T>(&self, callback: C) -> T where C: for<'a> Callback<&'a i32, CallbackResult = T>;` allows the code to compile.

Comment: Opened an issue for `'static`: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114801.