# Borrowed value does not live long enough, unsure why it's still borrowed

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm having an issue with the borrow checker; here's a simplified version of what I'm trying:

```rust
trait CommitmentScheme<In> {
    type Com;

    fn commit(input: In) -> Self::Com;
    
    fn open(com1: &Self::Com, com2: &Self::Com);
}

fn prove<CS: for<'a> CommitmentScheme<&'a [u32]>>() {
    let msg1 = vec![1u32];
    let com1 = CS::commit(&msg1);
    let msg2 = vec![2u32];
    let com2 = CS::commit(&msg2);
    CS::open(&com1, &com2);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=636d1bc91736dfc1644f62d79b0e1729)

This fails to compile with the following error,

```
error[E0597]: `msg2` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:13:27
   |
12 |     let msg2 = vec![2u32];
   |         ---- binding `msg2` declared here
13 |     let com2 = CS::commit(&msg2);
   |                           ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
14 |     CS::open(&com1, &com2);
15 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `msg2` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `com1` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `<CS as CommitmentScheme<&[u32]>>::Com`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

Declaring `msg2` earlier would avoid the error, but in my setting, `msg2` can't be built until after the first `commit` call.

My understanding of the issue is that it's possible for the returned `Com` to retain a reference to the committed message. However, it seems like each commitment should be dropped before the message it might reference, as per the opposite-order rule. I tried manually `drop`ing commitments first, but no luck.

I also tried declaring `type Com: 'static;`, which I thought would essentially guarantee that `commit` returns something borrow-free (except possibly static borrows which don't seem like an issue). I thought this would ensure that `msg1` and `msg2` only get borrowed during the `commit` call, not after, but the error persists.

Comment: I think the problem is that `for<'a> CommitmentScheme<&'a [u32]>` requires that both calls to `CS::commit()` provide an argument with the same lifetime, which requires `msg1` and `msg2` to have the same lifetime, but they don't.

Comment: Hmm, after some experimenting I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: You might be hitting this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76895814/501250

Comment: This works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=656bf1729c71cbdebf58a4ce515bcce6
Not sure how helpful this is, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each lifetime `'a` in the `for<'a>` imposes a *different* implementation. It is like `CS` implements `CommitmentScheme` multiple times, once for each lifetime. When `open()` takes `Self::Com`, it actually takes `<Self as CommitmentScheme<In>>::Com`, with `In` containing the actual lifetime used here. So the lifetimes must be equal for both parameters.

The reason `'static` doesn't work to specify the associated type as non-capturing lifetimes is explained in [issue #114801](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114801#issuecomment-1678317004), linked in [Tell the compiler that a generic return type doesn't borrow any references to arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76895814/tell-the-compiler-that-a-generic-return-type-doesnt-borrow-any-references-to-ar). The solution is to use a different generic parameter for `Com`, which can't borrow from the lifetime since it is not declared yet when it is declared:

```rust
fn prove<Com, CS: for<'a> CommitmentScheme<&'a [u32], Com = Com>>() {
    let msg1 = vec![1u32];
    let com1 = CS::commit(&msg1);
    let msg2 = vec![2u32];
    let com2 = CS::commit(&msg2);
    CS::open(&com1, &com2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind elaborating on why the lifetimes must be equal? Since `CS` impls `CommitmentScheme` multiple times as you said, shouldn't it be possible for the two `commit` calls use different lifetimes, with the second being a narrower lifetime where `msg2` is in scope?

Comment: @DanielLubarov The `commit()` calls can, but the `open()` call cannot. It uses the same implementation of `CommitmentScheme` for both parameters, so, same lifetime.